# jQuery Sliding Tabs: control options- NEXT/PREVIOUS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to control tabs with a next/previous options. This is my [JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kFNtX/1/). I have spent hours researching and found the method NEXT/PREVIOUS function in this [WEBSITE](http://css-tricks.com/jquery-ui-tabs-with-nextprevious/). I have replicated everything in my example but i am not getting any results. Can someone look at my [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kFNtX/1/) and tell me what I am doing wrong?

**NEXT/PREVIOUS jquery/js**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $tabs = $('#st_horizontal').tabs();
    $(".st_tab_view").each(function(i) {
        var totalSize = $(".st_tab_view").size() - 1;
        if (i != totalSize) {
            next = i + 2;
            $(this).append("<a href='#' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "'>Next Page &#187;</a>");
        }
        if (i != 0) {
            prev = i;
            $(this).append("<a href='#' class='prev-tab mover' rel='" + prev + "'>&#171; Prev Page</a>");
        }
    });
    $('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() {
        $tabs.tabs('select', $(this).attr("rel"));
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like you've put the next and prev tabs in the wrong place within your markup.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte, i plus one your comment. Could you tell me where exactly?

Comment: Try adding a separate click for next tab and prev tab and also try using `parseInt($(this).attr('rel'))`.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte, I don't think that's true. The next/prev button are added to the markup programmatically, via his JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to include the jQuery UI JS library to use jQuery UI Tabs. I edited your fiddle to include that and I got the next button displayed - http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/kFNtX/3/

Second, you are combining two tabs plugins together on the same DOM element (sliding tabs and jQuery UI tabs) - then you are trying to programmatically traverse them using the jQuery UI way. I don't think this will work very well. You need to choose one plugin to use.

Third, the sliding tabs plugin already provides you next and prev buttons. So I would suggest use the next/previous functions from the website you referred above only with jQuery UI tabs.

Hope this helps!

***Update***: This fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/PS336/ - demonstrates how the next/prev functionality can be achieved with Sliding Tabs.

Comment: thank you for the help. I plus one your answer. One last thing before i accept your answer, can you advise me of a solution for the "sliding tabs" that will have a next/previous option?

Comment: I have updated my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/PS336/) with a working example of how next/prev can be achieved with slidingTabs (note that I removed jQueryUI.js and also removed initialization of the jQuery UI Tabs). Sliding tabs doesn't expose any events/methods to select the next and prev tabs. So I improvised and triggered a click event on the tabs themselves. Tidy up the markup to position the next/prev buttons correctly and you have a fully working model. All the best!

Comment: Thank you! so much for your help. I plus one your comment and will accept your answer.

Comment: my friend it seems that you are the only that can help me. I am trying to disable the top menu tabs from being click. I want the user to go in order. Here is my code in [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PS336/3/). I have added a few lines of code but it is not working. Could you please help me?

Comment: You are mixing jQuery UI tabs here again. As I said before, you need to choose either jQuery UI tabs or Sliding Tabs - you can't use both on the same DOM element! Also, can you describe what you are trying to achieve in detail? I can advise whether to use jQuery UI tabs or Sliding tabs better that way.

Comment: Oh ok, I am starting to understand it. Sorry I am new to jquery. I want the user to go through the tabs in order(1,2,3,4,5, etc). So I want to disable the top menu completely. The user will be forced to only click Previous or Next. In other words the user will go in order through the tabs. I want to this with Sliding tabs and not UI. Here is an example but it is in UI: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979063/jquery-ui-tabs-how-can-i-disable-top-menu)